# How to create an Android TV app or launcher with an API-driven advertisement space at the bottom?

Tags: android, android-tv

I am interested in developing an Android TV app or launcher that incorporates a unique feature. I would like the app to function as a regular TV interface, but with an additional rectangular space at the bottom dedicated to displaying advertisements. These ads should be pushed to the app via an API.

I have a few questions regarding the feasibility and implementation of this idea:

- Is it possible to create a custom Android TV app or launcher that includes an ad space at the bottom?
- How can I design and implement the ad space in a way that does not disrupt the regular TV viewing experience?
- What are the recommended tools, frameworks, or libraries for building an Android TV app or launcher with API integration?
  I appreciate any guidance, advice, resources or examples that can help me get started with developing this Android TV app or launcher with an API-driven advertisement space. Thank you!